# How to solve this equation using mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

The equation is `y''[x] - 4*x*y[x] == -8*a1*(AiryAi[x])^2`. The solution  will be in the form of `y[x]->a2*AiryAi[2^(2/3) x] + F[x]`, where `F[x]` is the particular solution, `a1` and `a2` are the constants.  Boundary condition is y[infinity]->0.

Comment: Did you even try anything? ``DSolve[y''[x] - 4*x*y[x] == -8*C[1]*(AiryAi[x])^2, y, x]`` seems to work for me.

Comment: @b3m2a1...Actually I want y[x] to vanish at x-> infinity. So I tried DSolve[y''[x] - 4*x*y[x] == -8*a1*(AiryAi[x])^2, 
 y[\[Infinity]] == 0, y, x]. But it did not work..How to give bc at infinity?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my lazy take on this from the ~5 min I looked at it. [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) does this just fine without the BC so we'll do:

```
sol1 = DSolveValue[y''[x] - 4*x*y[x] == -8*C[1]*(AiryAi[x])^2, y, x]

Function[{x}, 
 AiryAi[2^(2/3) x] C[2] + AiryBi[2^(2/3) x] C[3] + 
  AiryBi[2^(2/3) x] Integrate[-4 2^(
     1/3) π AiryAi[K[2]]^2 AiryAi[2^(2/3) K[2]] C[1], {K[2], 1, 
     x}] + AiryAi[2^(2/3) x] Integrate[
    4 2^(1/3) π AiryAi[K[1]]^2 AiryBi[2^(2/3) K[1]] C[1], {K[1], 
     1, x}]
 ]
```

Then we have those nasty `Integrate` expressions in there so for a first-order approach we'll handle them numerically and just see what pops out:

```
Table[
   NIntegrate[
    4 2^(1/3) π AiryAi[K[1]]^2 AiryBi[2^(2/3) K[1]], {K[1], 1, 
     x}], 
   {x, 1, 100, 1}
   ] // ListLinePlot
```

[image: blah]

And this does weird stuff around 65 but Mathematica also emits cads of `NIntegrate` issues around there too so we'll just assume it's round off. That first part looks a lot like a `Log` type function so we'll just approximate it as a `Log` for now.

```
b /. First@
  Solve[Log[b, 60] == 
    NIntegrate[
     4 2^(1/3) π AiryAi[K[1]]^2 AiryBi[2^(2/3) K[1]], {K[1], 1, 
      60}], b]

2.5009
```

Then we do the same for the other integral:

```
Table[
  NIntegrate[-4 2^(
    1/3) π AiryAi[K[2]]^2 AiryAi[2^(2/3) K[2]] , {K[2], 1, x}], 
  {x, 1, 100, 1}
  ] // ListLinePlot
```

[image: blah2]

And since you seem to care most about the long-time behavior (and that this decays to `0`) we'll just call this the constant it converges to:

```
NIntegrate[-4 2^(
  1/3) π AiryAi[K[2]]^2 AiryAi[2^(2/3) K[2]] , {K[2], 1, 100}]

-0.0037991
```

With this in hand we can get a handle on our solution:

```
sol2 =
  Function[{x},
   AiryAi[2^(2/3) x] C[2] +
    AiryBi[2^(2/3) x] C[3] +
    C[1]*(
      AiryBi[2^(2/3) x] Log[2.5, x] +
       AiryAi[2^(2/3) x] (-.0037991)
      )
   ];
```

And first we'll try with all of our constants being `1`:

```
Plot[sol2[x] /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1, C[3] -> 1} // Evaluate, {x, 1, 
  10}]
```

[image: blah]

And this blows up and this can be blamed on the `AiryBi` term:

```
Plot[AiryBi[2^(2/3) x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image: blah]

And to kill off our `AiryBi` terms we need to set `C[1]` and `C[3]` to `0` which gives us the entirely boring solution:

```
AiryAi[2^(2/3) x] C[2]
```

Maybe there's a way to get a solution that isn't trivial, but this is what my off-the-cuff analysis seems to give.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the help of *Mathematica*, I needed considerable manual intervention to obtain the following solution:

```
AiryAi[2^(2/3) x] (3^(2/3) C[1] Gamma[2/3] +
                   4 2^(1/3) a1 π (Integrate[AiryAi[u]^2 AiryBi[2^(2/3) u],
                                             {u, 0, x}] -
                                   Sqrt[3] Integrate[AiryAi[u]^2 AiryAi[2^(2/3) u],
                                                     {u, 0, ∞}])) +
4 2^(1/3) a1 π AiryBi[2^(2/3) x] Integrate[AiryAi[u]^2 AiryAi[2^(2/3) u], {u, x, ∞}]
```

You can check that the solution takes the value `C[1]` when `x == 0`, and has the desired decay at $\infty$. I'll write up the long story of how I got this expression later if anybody's interested.

Comment: can you please share the code to get this solution and plots of the solution vs x.